# IE 7 DIV class name change issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am facing an issue in IE7 when I try to change the class name of a particular `DIV`.

Essentially there are 2 classes, one is a grayed-out button the other is a normal button. Both classes toggle with respect to some condition. In IE7 when I first try to change the class name it changes correctly, but when I try to switch it back it disappears and it comes back once I click again on the page.

This seems like some rendering issue. I cannot figure out why the first class changes correctly to grayed-out state, but it does not work correctly when the toggle condition changes so that the button should go back to normal, and it rather becomes invisible?

IE 8+ and firefox, chrome are rendering it properly. Any thoughts?

PS note: mask class has no style attributes just a name identifier.

CSS code:

```
.darkClass
{
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* IE */
    opacity: 0.5; /* Safari, Opera */
    -moz-opacity:0.50; /* FireFox */
    z-index: 200;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;

    display: block;
}
```

JS code:

```
if(flagButton==true) //toggle condition
{                          
    // this block shows the normal button    
    document.ChangePwdExpiredForm.submitHidden1.disabled=false;
    document.getElementById('changPwdsubmit').className='mask';
}
else
{                          
   // this block shows the greyedout 
   buttondocument.ChangePwdExpiredForm.submitHidden1.disabled=true;
   document.getElementById("changPwdsubmit").className="darkClass";
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="button_login" id="button_login">
  <div class="mask" id="changPwdsubmit">
    <div class="imageButton2">
      <a href="javascript:submitMask1();" onclick="submitMask1();return false" class="loginButton2_right">
        <span >
          <bean:message key="button.transaction.continue"/>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what is the bean that is referenced ?

Comment: Could be a `typo`.. you are missing the closing tag of parent `div` here..

Comment: I'm afraid this code isn't enough to solve the problem, everything seems to be fine. Can you save a working example to http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: The bean is referenced, for the text value of the button. Yes, the div seems to be the typo..ill put the code on js fiddle.